# Why cant mingw find libraries that gcc can find?

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64

I am trying to compile a c program for windows and ubuntu to do that i am using mingw but it seems that it cant find the required libraries that gcc can find
when i execute this command

```
gcc decode_video.c -o dv -lavcodec -lavutil
```

Everything compiles normally but when i use this

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc decode_video.c -o dv.exe -lavcodec -lavutil
```

it says that header files arent found

after changing the build command to

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc decode_video.c -o dv.exe -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l avcodec -l avutil
```

it know gives me this error even though the libraries are linked

```
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `avcodec_send_packet'
```

/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x192): undefined reference to `avcodec_receive_frame'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x33f): undefined reference to`av_packet_alloc'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x37d): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x3d0): undefined reference to`av_parser_init'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x421): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x481): undefined reference to`avcodec_open2'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x512): undefined reference to `av_frame_alloc'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x5fc): undefined reference to`av_parser_parse2'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x6f8): undefined reference to `av_parser_close'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x707): undefined reference to`avcodec_free_context'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x716): undefined reference to `av_frame_free'
/tmp/ccgn1NTi.o:decode_video.c:(.text+0x722): undefined reference to`av_packet_free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: What header files?

Comment: decode_video.c:34:10: fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it turned that you tried to link against libraries for an incompatible architecture:

> Why can't mingw find libraries that gcc can find?

- Either compiler are using different default options for the linker.
- Even with same `-L <path>` and same `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc., the linker will skip incompatible libraries.  In your case, `gcc` is presumably hosted by 
  `x86_64-linux-gnu`, whereas `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` is obviously hosted by `x86_64-w64-mingw32`.  Both are incompatible.

---

1. Try adding `-I <path>` to the compilation where `<path>` contains `libavcodec/avcodec.h`.  Add more `-I` if you need more paths.  Use `-isystem <path>` if it's supposed to be system headers.  Add `-v -H` to the compilation to see what include paths are in use. gcc prints:

   ```
   #include "..." search starts here:
   #include <...> search starts here:
   ```
2. Try adding `-L <path>` to the link stage where `<path>` contains the libraries like `lib*.a` / `lib*.so` to be linked against.  Add `-Wl,-v` to see which options the compiler driver passes to the GNU linker `ld`.
3. Make sure the symbols are in the libraries, e.g. using tools like `nm` or `x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm`.
4. Make sure you are using libraries cross-compiled using the `x86_64-w64-mingw32` toolchain.

Comment: this is exactly what i did you can see it in the edited command these directories are for headers and and lib.a locations and it generated that aeerror

Comment: https://pastebin.com/w18A1tsf this is a link to verbose output

Comment: Are the symbols in that said libraries?

Comment: yes i have checked them and if they werent how would it compile with gcc

Comment: @Wajdi Muhtadi : Your aren't trying to use the same libraries, do you? See 4. in my answer. You need libs cross-compiled with `x86_64-w64-mingw32` toolchain.

Comment: how can i get these libraries

Comment: Configure them with `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32` in the case they are using GNU autotools) or get appropriate host libraries from somewhere.